# Почему рестарт сервера делается очень долго?

Tags: centos

Сервер Centos 7, сделал рестарт и висит так очень долго, в прошлий раз было примерно пол часа, а щас уже 40 минут.
На мониторе - ничего, чёрный экран.
Что можно делать чтобы он быстрее включился?

---

параметры железки:

- Оперативная память: 96 GB
- Файл подкачки (swap): 4095 MiB
- Процессор: 2 X Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5670 @ 2.93GHz (12 cores)

Comment: уже включился, но всё-же интересно

Comment: всего рестарт занял 43 минут

Comment: Проблемы с сетевыми устройствами?

Comment: нет, сам сервер не стартует, но рестарт делаю из ISPmanager

Comment: Вы наверное понимаете, что для ответа надо хотя бы знать конфигурацию вашей системы и посмотреть логи загрузки. Раз вы упомянули ISPmanager, рискну предположить, что речь идет о виртуальной машине у какого-то провайдера. Если это так, то что он отвечает на ваш запрос? А какие устройства монтируете при буте и где они физически? Иногда очень долго стартует при загрузке с raid, если с ним (raid-ом) проблемы

Comment: добавил конфигураций, сервер не от провайдера, а наш, физически есть к нему доступ

Comment: А в логах что прочитали?

Comment: `autosolve=on&
elid=1&
func=services.restart.problem` но может быть не там смотрю

Comment: Да, логов там немало. [Это все смотрели?](https://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-interpret-system-log-files/) А [тут, пожалуй, написано лучше](https://habr.com/post/332502/)

Comment: спасибо за ссылки, почитаю